# Не получается сделать статический метод для чтения

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток. Только только изучаю PHP, имеется задача реализовать статический метод для чтения текстового файла который лежит в папке, делал так:

```
public static function readOn($name)
    {
            chdir(self::$dir);
            $str = file_get_contents($name);
            $str = ($str);
            return $str;
    }

    public static function __toString()
    {
        return self::readOn($name);
    }
```

как не пытался ничего не выводится. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка и как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Этому злу вас пытается научить GeekBrains ? :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В принципе - все правильно. За исключением нескольких "но".

1. `public static function __toString()` - это вообще к чему? У всех классов есть "магический" метод `__toString()`, который автоматически запускается при попытке преобразовать экземпляр класса в строку и который можно переопределить. Вот только он - не static. Создается впечатление, что Вы пытались создать статический класс, но запутались в стандартных встроенных "магических" методах. На заметку - почитайте про ["магические" методы](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.magic.php).
2. `$str = ($str);` полностью соответствует `$str = $str;` и не несет никакого смысла.
3. Вы не привели исходник всего класса. Но исходя из приведенного кода можно предположить, что Вы делали его полностью статитическим, т.е. все поля и методы класса - статические. В то же время в сформулированной Вами задаче сказано:

> имеется задача реализовать **статический метод** для чтения текстового файла который лежит в папке

Можно, конечно, сделать весь класс полностью статическим. Вот только тогда каталог, где лежат файлы, (`self::$dir`) будет "один на всех", и перед тем, как прочитать файл из другого каталога, Вам придется поменять настройки своего статического класса. А потом - вернуть назад, если нужно будет снова работать с предыдущим каталогом. Вероятность появления ошибки возрастает. Если в условии сказано, что статическим должен быть *метод*, который читает  файл, то для дальнейшей работы с объектами класса проще выполнить условие буквально. Т.е. *реализовать класс с одним статическим методом*. Что-то типа

```php
class FileReader
{
   protected $dir, $filename;
   protected $fileContent;
   protected $error;

   public function ___construct(string $filename, string $dir = './') {
      $this->dir = $dir;
      $this->filename = $filename;
      try {
         $this->fileContent = self::readOn($dir . $filename);
      } catch (Exception $e) {
         $this->error = $e->getMessage();
      }
   }

   public function __toString() {
      return $this->fileContent ?? $this->error;
   }

    public static function readOn($name) {
        $str = file_get_contents($name);
        if ($str === false) {
            throw new Exception("File $name cann't be readed.");
        }
        return $str;
    }
}
```

Тогда его использование может выглядеть примерно так:

```php
// file1.txt расположен в текущей директории
$file1 = new FileReader('file1.txt');

// вывести содержимое file1.txt
echo $file1;

// file2.txt расположен в родительской директории
$file2 = new FileReader('file2.txt', '../');

// вывести содержимое file2.txt
echo $file2;
```

Если произошла ошибка чтения файла, то при преобразовании в строку вместо содержимого файла будет выведено сообщение об ошибке `File ... cann't be readed.`

P.S. Класс можно еще улучшить, исключив из него `$dir`. Если файл лежит не в текущей директории, то в параметре $filename конструктора можно передать абсолютный или относительный путь к файлу, например - так: `$file = new FileReader('../file.txt');`. Это изменение Вы сможете сделать самостоятельно.

P.P.S. Посмотреть значения переменных в процессе выполнения скрипта можно с помощью [var_dump()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.var-dump.php). "Разобрать" полное имя файла на составляющие можно с помощью [pathinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php). Если исключения ([Exception](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.exception.php)) и их обработку ([try ... catch](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php)) еще не проходили - удалите этот код из класса вместе с protected $error.

**Update**

> Сама задача звучит так: Cоздайте класс со статическим полем dir="text" Создайте два статических метода в классе: на чтение и на запись в файле. Имя файла передается в параметре метода, а в метод на запись в файл передается ещё и строка, которую нужно дописать в файл, а директория берется из статического поля.

Тогда - так:

```php
class FileReader
{
   public static $dir = "text";

    public static function readOn($filename) {
        $lastSymbol = substr(self::$dir, -1);
        $insertSeparator = ($lastSymbol !== '\\' && $lastSymbol !== '/');
        $fullname = self::$dir . ($insertSeparator ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR : '')
                    . $filename;
        // раскомментируй чтобы перепроверить что получилось в имени файла
        //var_dump($fullname);

        return file_get_contents($fullname);
    }
}

$content = FileReader::readOn('file.txt');

echo 'Содержимое файла file.txt в каталоге ' . FileReader::$dir . ":\n";
var_dump($content);

FileReader::$dir = 'txt';

$content = FileReader::readOn('file.txt');

echo 'Содержимое файла file.txt в каталоге ' . FileReader::$dir . ":\n";
var_dump($content);
```

С записью, надеюсь, справитель сами. Ознакомьтесь с [файловыми функциями PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.filesystem.php).

Comment: Сама задача звучит так:
Cоздайте класс со статическим полем dir="text"
Создайте два статических метода в классе: на чтение и на запись в файле. Имя файла передается в параметре метода, а в метод на запись в файл передается ещё и строка, которую нужно дописать в файл, а директория берется из статического поля.

Comment: Уважаемый автор ответа. Я минус поставил вам не потому что плохой ответ, а потому что этот ответ пораждает ад на всей нашей планете. Кто то ведь задает такие задачи, а есть еще люди которые просят помочь в ответах на эти задачи. И, короче говоря, нахрен надо.

Comment: Уважаемый @zalex, если Вы вспомните свое детство, то возможно поймете, почему в 1 классе Вас учили алфавиту, в 3-4 поручали составить рассказ из 3-5 связанных предложений, и только много позже дрючили за стиль, форму и содержание сочинения на 3-4 страницы. Помочь третьекласнику связно написать рассказ "Как я провел лето" - снизить уровень энтропии во Вселенной. IMHO. Я помогаю тому, кто _пытается работать самостоятельно_. Пытаюсь привить привычку сверяться с документацией, снижая количество обращений за помощью в тривиальных случаях. А то потом придется с _недоученным_ работать - нахрен надо?

Comment: Я просто хочу чтоб вы меня правильно поняли, что очень хочется что бы данный ресурс приносил пользу, а не плодил сопли, где миллион вопросов задается только лишь от лени найти ответ самому. Более того, автор вопроса явно обучается, раз ему дают такие задания. 
Вот вы приводите пример про 1 класс, а не думаете ли вы что автор вопроса уже прочитал алфавит, но ничего там не понял. Может ему стоит еще раз его перечитать или хотя бы задать вопрос преподавателю своему, а не плодить бесполезные для ресурса вопросы, которые засирают не только экран, но и головы. Извините если чем то обидел. я со зла.

Comment: @zalex, я понимаю Вашу позицию, но не поддерживаю. Кажется, большАя часть сообщества также не поддерживает: ["Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос."](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1028826/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%bb-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c). А польза... _Обмен опытом_ - тоже форма _обучения_. Я и сам учусь тут.:)